# Net salary decreasing over time

Tags: salary

PREMISE: similar questions have been asked in the field of software engineering, but I work in a more niche area (software engineering applied to aerospace) where is more difficult to find people with understanding of both software and aerospace engineering.

I am working in a software engineering company in a country where you get tax exemptions in the first five years spent as resident. The offer I got here is not as competitive as in other countries, but this is offset by fiscal exemptions.

I knew this when I accepted, but there were other things which I am learning now as I am spending time here.

The main problem is, as I am finding out from elder colleagues, that the salary increases over these five years are less than the decrease I am going to experience at the end of the exemptions.

I am also learning, always from my coworkers, that promotions and salary increases are tied quite rigidly on the number of years spent at the company, and not much influenced by performance and previous experience. For example, entry level salary is the same whether you have a PhD in computer science/software engineering or a MSc. As a further example, senior employees involved into several projects are paid the same employees who barely show up at the workplace and work on fewer projects (I know everyone’s approx salary and projects because our manager share budget info with us). Same thing from other factors such as networking.

Furthermore, management positions seem to be precluded to people with a technical background: all managers have MBAs or a legal background. This is slowing down even further promotion opportunities as there is this sort of formal ceiling for technical staff.

Therefore, not only I am feeling like on a dead end, but I know already that in a few years I will likely make less than now, which is not really good for my morale.

My question is: would it feel acceptable (especially for perspective employers) if I start job hunting now (I have been here for 15 months)? Or should I start at the end of the five-year exemption even if I see better openings?

Comment: Welcome to the site @northernlight! You've provided quite a bit of context here but it's still not quite clear to me what your most pressing concern is. Do you *want* to stay with this company? And why are you making the decision binary between "leave now after just over a year" and "stay for another 4"? It sounds like you should simply monitor how your salary evolves over time and if it's no longer in line with your market value either make the case for a raise or leave. Are these "exemptions" only realised if you stay the full five years?

Comment: To answer to both: I could apply to another job anytime from now to the end of the exempted period or after as well. What I meant is that there are openings right now, in which salary is higher because companies offer more and not because of an exemption: the higher salary is *potentially* forever, the exemption is bound to end no matter what (and when it ends, I will still want to find another place that pays according to my experience. That’s what drives me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, this fiscal rule only applies if I stay in the same countries. Another difference, as I wrote above, is salary: often twice as much. I know what I will be getting beforehand, because this time I have more time to collect information on perspective employers. When I accepted here I really had a bad period due a combination of incumbent health issues: I knew what I was getting into, but that was what I had back then. I had to put aside my long term vision for a while. That’s still my fault ofc, but I can’t see that happening again.

Comment: If selected, I could, there is a significant chance. I am wondering if I should quit now (15 months) or stay for at least the exempted period for a question of loyalty to my employer. On the other hand, after these 5 years, I will change, loyal or not.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is your first job. The switch out of the first job can be a big psychological challenge. Most senior folks would say that the question "is it okay to look for another job?" is a no-brainer _yes_ in this and most other situations, as well.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: would it feel acceptable (especially for perspective employers) if I start job hunting now (I have been here for 15 months)?

Yes. 15 months and lack of advancement options are a perfectly good reason that will be acceptable to almost all future employers.

Probably the most tricky question you may get about this is "Why did you take the job in the first place? What type of research did you do to determine that this was a good choice for you and how will you prevent this in the future?"

Comment: When I applied, we were still in the pandemics. I had already lost an opportunity in which I was going to be hired but then they lost funding, and other former colleagues had really experiences too. At that time grabbing the opportunity seemed the best thing to do.

Comment: @northernlight That's a question you're expected to answer in an interview, not here.

Comment: Of course! Still, that’s the short answer.

Comment: @northernlight: it doesn't matter what you answer here (and there is no need to justify anything) . Focus on going forward: what will you say if it comes up in an interview?  If you don't know, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in such dead end starting job hunting after 15 months is reasonable, but is it practical? You have a very specialised skill what is the possibility that eventually you get an offer from a company that is not so different from the one you are leaving?

How long should one stay in a workplace depends on many factors, not just the salary. You should also take into account the experience you are doing on the job. If you are still learning new things it could be worth to stay on for some more time. After all thinking that you can start searching now or wait until the end of the five years period is a bit oversimplified, there are 45 months in between. Forget the idea that you have to quickly grab the opportunity that shows up. If the economy does not change sooner or later a new opportunity will show up. If the economy crashes no job would be safe anyway.

Comment: You can find most of the answers in the comments below my original post. As for learning, we are being a bit short staffed and I am working between 50-60 hours/week. I am spending a lot of time on training interns but I am having not so much time to study latest developments in my field.

Comment: @northernlight In this case if you start job hunting now I don't think that perspective employers will find it odd. Often employers know well the working conditions in the other companies in their segment.